# Jquery Hide/Show happening repeatedly on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

So I have two `div`s that are placed exactly on top of each other and have the same dimensions. By default `div A` should be shown but when someone hovers over the area, `div A` has been programmed by `Jquery` to `.hide()` and `div B` has been programmed to `.show()` . In the same way, when the hovering ends, the display should go back to default. I have done this using the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` functions.

When I pass no arguments with the `show()` and `hide()` functions, it works perfectly. But suppose I do something like `.show(800)` and `.hide(800)` or `.show("slow")` and `.hide("slow")` the animation keeps happening repeatedly for a while and then stops. `Div B` shows, then hides and at the same time `Div A` hides and shows, repeatedly. The `.mouseover()` / `.mouseout()` function is applied to the parent `div` of both A and B.

I am aware of the `.stop()` function and that solves the problem to a great extent but not quite. I have hyperlinked text on `Div B` where the link hover animation keeps flickering when `Div B` is shown.

Here is a link to the website. http://nd2cindia.com/test_teams_display/ (I am using `.show()` and `.hide()` functions for now until this problem is resolved. )

Here is my Jquery

```
$(".parent").mouseover(function () {
  $("> .A", this).hide("800");
  $("> .B", this).show("800");
});

$(".teambox").mouseout(function () {
  $("> .A", this).show("800");
  $("> .B", this).hide("800");
});
```

Comment: Can you replace to the not working version? So we could see the problem..

Comment: You better use css animation rather than jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want.I wrote style internally.you can change it as you want.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="a" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green; position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;">
</div>
<div class="b" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:orange;position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px">
</div>


<!-- js--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    });

 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help to you. I suggest you to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Answer (score 2):

I am every time using:

```
$("selector").stop().show();
$("selector2").stop().hide();
```

It stops all running animations and run from actual state.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you had duplicate IDs (***#team_name_id***). This is not valid, so I removed the IDs and added a class - you should make your own changes, which will cause you to update your CSS.

Firstly, I've created a named function which you can apply to your events instead of an anonymous one - it's often better to do this, as it allows you to separate your concerns - and is more DRY.

Secondly, because you're toggling, and there is no other logic required - you can use a single function. You may want to separate this out in the future to give you batter control and logic.

```
var hoverToggle = function () {
  // Toggling an element will bring it into view or hide it, and it will do so with a queue.
  // Anything more complex than this, you'll need to make your own queue
  $(this).find('.players_display, .beforehover').stop().toggle(800)
}
```

You'll notice that I've use '***this***' which provides context and stops the events bubbling outside of the boxes you've created. It also means they're easier to find.

You'll also notice that I've used a comma separated *selector* which finds both sets. Another benefit of using a *toggle* is that it'll treat each element independently. So, while one show()s the other hide()s.

I find ***hover()*** to be a better function call - as it make tidier code. Simply call your function within it. The same can be done with other functions other than hover () if you prefer.

```
$('.teambox').hover(hoverToggle, hoverToggle);
```

jsFiddle to demo: https://jsfiddle.net/likestothink/ndfbhw02/1/